# Powershell's Invoke-Command won't take in a variable for -ComputerName parameter

Tags: windows, powershell-4.0

I just can't seem to get this to work, and I can't figure out how to google this issue. similar script is working remotly but now i need to made it work localy. But... Please check the script...

```
Function Local-Install {
$ComputerName = "$env:computername"
$AppName = "Deployment"

Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName ,$AppName -ScriptBlock `
{
param ($ComputerName,$AppName)
write-host "Getting Parameters for '$AppName' on $ComputerName"}
$Application = Get-WmiObject -computername $ComputerName -Namespace "root\ccm\ClientSDK" -Class CCM_Application | where {$_.Name -like "$AppName"} | Select-Object Id, Revision, IsMachineTarget
$AppID = $Application.Id
$AppRev = $Application.Revision
$AppTarget = $Application.IsMachineTarget
([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSdk:CCM_Application').Install($AppID, $AppRev, $AppTarget, 0, 'Normal', $False) 
}
```

and i get an error like this:

```
Invoke-Command : One or more computer names are not valid. If you are trying to pass a URI, use the -ConnectionUri parameter, or pass URI objects ins
tead of strings.
At line:5 char:1
+ Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName ,$AppName -ScriptBlock `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (System.String[]:String[]) [Invoke-Command], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PSSessionInvalidComputerName,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand

Exception calling "Install" : ""
At line:13 char:1
+ ([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSdk:CCM_Application').Install($AppID, $AppRev, $AppTa ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WMIMethodException
```

Comment: It looks like the syntax of the $ComputerName is just not valid. Can you try printing out what the variable gets set to?

Comment: I've added write host after the param section but did not get any resolt, but after running the script pasted write-host "Getting Parameters for '$AppName' on $ComputerName"
Getting Parameters for 'Deployment' on WX0000

Comment: I believe i figured out, there is no need variables above the invoke command, just added it to the parameter section as a strings

Answer (score 0):

Since this is local you could just run the "env:COMPUTERNAME" call in the method. However, if you want to get this to work as is, you just need to add the -ArgumentList argument to the Invoke-Command call:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName, $AppName -ArgumentList $ComputerName, $AppName -ScriptBlock `
```

Comment: If i understand you coretly script should be looking like this?
`Function Local-Install {
$ComputerName = "$env:computername"
$AppName = "Deployment"
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName, $AppName -ArgumentList $ComputerName, $AppName -ScriptBlock `{other lines}`